# Días de la semana

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que me devuelva todos los días del mes ejemplo :1,2,3 etc... Sobre una grafica pero solo me pinta los días en los que hay ventas y necesito que me refleje todos los días del mes presente, A continuación anexo el código que estoy utilizando.

```
$sql="SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM fecha_inicio) AS dia,precio FROM `reserva`; ";

$cad='';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 
{
  $cad = $cad."['".$fila['dia']."',  ".$fila['precio']."],";
}

$cad=substr($cad,0,strlen($cad)-1);
```

Comment: que versión de php y MySQL tienes?

Answer (score 1):

creas un rango de fechas o días, y en base a ello le haces un left join a tu tabla de ventas por el día.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
WITH RECURSIVE rango_de_fechas (d) AS
(
  SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 31 DAY
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM rango_de_fechas WHERE d + INTERVAL 1 day <= CURDATE()
)
SELECT YEAR(d) `año`, MONTH(d) `mes` , DAY(d) `dia`
FROM  rango_de_fechas
  ORDER BY dia, año, mes;
```

Código funcional:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6rWdUX7PKehGMsNa3MPNXy/1

Comment: Todo esta dentro de una sola tabla no tengo que unir tablas , tengo la inforamacion dentro de una tabla llamada reserva y alli con fecha_inicio muestro las ventas pero solo me muesta el dia donde hicieron ventas , no todo los dias del mes actual asi no hallan ventas

Comment: por eso te digo esta consulta genera todos los días y en base al día debes seleccionar una reserva si está, se mostrará, pero sino, no esta no se agrega pero si te saca el día.

Comment: estas tratando de sacar valores vacíos, si están en null podrías tratar de reemplazar el valor con algo para que te saque todos los días

Comment: Exacto y en mi consulta como remplazo ese null?

Comment: usa [coalesce](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/03/07/mysql-coalescencia-coalesce)